# kendo window close action event not unbind jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is my sampe code:

```
var confirmDialog = $(dialogId).data("kendoWindow");

confirmDialog.bind("close",customFunction);

$(okBtnId).click(function(){

confirmDialog.unbind("close",customFunction);
confirmDialog.close();
});
```

whenever i click ok button it calls my function customFunction i already unbinded the function.

Please Help.

Comment: are you getting the correct value of dialogId?

Comment: have you got a minimum, reproducible and working example?